# Почему в тип данных из двух бит я не могу записать нужное мне число?

Tags: c++, c

Есть структура, которая хранит чимсло из 2 бит, все верно же?

```
struct Bytes2InNumber{
    int a:2;
};
```

Создал объект, записываю число 2, т.е (00 = 0,01 = 1, 10 = 2, 11 = 3).

```
struct Bytes2InNumber bits_2_in_number;
bytes_2_in_number.a = 2;
printf("Number with 2 bytes: %d\n", bytes_2_in_number.a);
```

Вывод printf:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу прощения за, быть может, глупость, никогда этим раньше не занимался и что происходит - не понимаю

В printf написано bytes, ну я про биты говорю, не обращайте внимания, описался

Comment: Запишите его как `unsigned` - а то у вас первый бит - знак...

Comment: @Harry А, господи. Такая глупая ошибка, спасибо)

Comment: @Harry А почему в минус уходит, в чем природа этого поведения?

Comment: Вот, почитайте тут - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4 Просто у вас то же самое, но для 2 битов :)

Answer (score 2):

При использовании `int` есть такая вещь, как *знаковый бит*, поэтому у вас записываются числа не 0-3, а от -2 до 1...

Вот такое изменение

```
struct Bytes2InNumber{
    unsigned int a:2;
};
```

должно вам помочь...